# How to become an administrator for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Here is the situation:

1. I Installed VS2013
2. That comes with SQL Server Express
3. I am not able to create a DB from VS2013
4. thinking that it's because of user privilege issues, I Installed SQL Server Management Studio
5. I have looked to figure out how to give myself Administrator privileges on SQL Server, and nothing has worked so far
6. I am the administrator of my Windows7
7. I run the SQL Server Management Studio as Administrator

Still I get error messages about not having permission to perform this action: Error 15247

Any ideas what I need to do to have permission

[Link to image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ7Qh.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you actually install SQL Server ?

Comment: The express version got installed automatically with Visual Studio 2013 . I see it in Control Panel

Comment: Go to run type `Services.msc` and then try to find `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` in the list of services and make sure it is running. If it is express then it may say something like `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`

Comment: I included the error message in my original question. It looks like one is started (not running) and one stops right after starting

Comment: @user1298925: SQL Server Agent service is not necessary for basic operations on the DB Engine, making it a red herring for your current issue. SQL Server itself is running, so that is fine.

Comment: Ok so one thing is established that you have sql server and it is running, now how are you trying to create a database from Visual Studio?

Comment: 1- Would you say its running? it just says it started though.

Comment: Just make sure that is it running, if it isn't running then right click go into properties and set it to start `Automatic` and then start the services.

Comment: did you select the server name from the drop down list? Error suggests that you are selecting the wrong server name. If you didnt have any sql server installed before the chances are that this SQL Server in a default instance, in that case you will need to only enter the `MachineName` , if it is a named instance then you will have enter the `MachineName\SQLEXPRESS` in server name section.

Comment: I was not allowed to edit my comment for 5 minutes, thus my dealy in response. I have doen exactly as you suggested in your answer and I am getting the error message that I added to my original question.  I was thrown off by the person who has voted my question as off topic to be closed, I don't understand some of these closure votes.  I hope the question stays open because I can't see the problem with it

Comment: I am not the one who voted it but this question has been asked before many times and if you search online you will find plenty of references about this issue and it is a very basic connectivity issue.

Comment: I am one step closer by adding MachineName\SQLEXPRESS / However now the error message says: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68309/discussion-between-user1298925-and-m-ali).

Comment: I found  this answer that solved my problem

[Answer to Admin Lockout by AlexS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188404/1298925

Comment: I found this answer in SO which solved my problem.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188404/1298925

Answer (score 2):

Since you have made sure that you have SQL Server installed on your machine all is left is to make sure that you follow the following steps to create a database.

1) Go to `Server Explorer` right click `Data Connections` and Select `Create New Sql Server Database...`

[image]

2) This will open a pop-up window enter your `MachineName\SQLEXPRESS` in Server Name section or select a server name from the Drop down list.

3) Enter the `New Database Name..` .

[image]

And you are good to go.

Comment: I am one step closer by adding MachineName\SQLEXPRESS  / However now the error message says: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master.

Comment: Are you logged in as an account with Admin rights on your pc? if so use use "Windows Authentication" to connect to sql server.

Comment: Yes I am logged in with Administrator rights.  I am clueless why this thing is not working. But I am looking all over internet